# The logic behind 'adapter'? (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adapter')

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I'm trying to implement a code I found for a list that returns the item selected in kivy.
The code works as an indepedent app. But I can't figure out how it is working step by step to implement it within my own application (using mainly the kv lang).

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

# Note the special nature of indentation in the adapter declaration, where
# the adapter: is on one line, then the value side must be given at one level
# of indentation.

Builder.load_string("""
#:import lv kivy.uix.listview
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
<MainView>:
    ListViewModal

<ListViewModal>:
    list_view: list_view_id
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 400,400
    ListView:
        id: list_view_id
        size_hint: .8,.8
        adapter:
            la.ListAdapter(
            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in xrange(10)],
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=False,
            cls=lv.ListItemButton)
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    selected_item = StringProperty('no selection')
    list_view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_view.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.selection_changed)

    # This is for the binding set up at instantiation, to the list adapter's
    # special on_selection_change (bind to it, not to adapter.selection).
    def selection_changed(self, *args):
        print '    args when selection changes gets you the adapter', args
        self.selected_item = args[0].selection[0].text

    # This is to illustrate another type of binding. This time it is to this
    # class's selected_item StringProperty (where the selected item text is set).
    # See other examples of how bindings are set up between things. This one
    # works because if you put on_ in front of a Kivy property name, a binding
    # is set up for you automatically.
    def on_selected_item(self, *args):
        print '    args when a list property changes gets you the list property, and the changed item', args
        print 'selected item text', args[1]

class MainView(GridLayout):
    """
    Implementation of a ListView using the kv language.
    """

    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # kwargs['cols'] = 1
        # kwargs['size_hint'] = (1.0, 1.0)
        # super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # listview_modal = ListViewModal()
        # self.add_widget(listview_modal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory

# Note the special nature of indentation in the adapter declaration, where
# the adapter: is on one line, then the value side must be given at one level
# of indentation.

Builder.load_string("""
#:import lv kivy.uix.listview
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
<MainView>:
    ListViewModal

<ListViewModal>:
    list_view: list_view_id
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 400,400
    ListView:
        id: list_view_id
        size_hint: .8,.8
        adapter:
            la.ListAdapter(
            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in xrange(10)],
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=False,
            cls=lv.ListItemButton)
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    selected_item = StringProperty('no selection')
    list_view = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.list_view.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.selection_changed)

    # This is for the binding set up at instantiation, to the list adapter's
    # special on_selection_change (bind to it, not to adapter.selection).
    def selection_changed(self, *args):
        print '    args when selection changes gets you the adapter', args
        self.selected_item = args[0].selection[0].text

    # This is to illustrate another type of binding. This time it is to this
    # class's selected_item StringProperty (where the selected item text is set).
    # See other examples of how bindings are set up between things. This one
    # works because if you put on_ in front of a Kivy property name, a binding
    # is set up for you automatically.
    def on_selected_item(self, *args):
        print '    args when a list property changes gets you the list property, and the changed item', args
        print 'selected item text', args[1]

class MainView(GridLayout):
    """
    Implementation of a ListView using the kv language.
    """
    pass
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # kwargs['cols'] = 1
        # kwargs['size_hint'] = (1.0, 1.0)
        # super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # listview_modal = ListViewModal()
        # self.add_widget(listview_modal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))
```

It raises me this error:

"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'adapter'"

I have read the documentation about 'adapter' but it's pretty new to me and I can't figure out why do I need an adapter for the list to return a result?

Comment: ListView and its stuff are [deprecated](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4944).

Comment: So how should I replace it then?

Comment: Use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html). :)